# Git - How to update master branch on my machine without loss of work?

Tags: git

Version control is something new for me. I searched for about my problem but I did not found the answer I would like. Maybe I'm not using the correct terms.

I'm working in some new features of a project. I took the master branch last week and started to work. Now, the master branch on remote is more updated than mine because another guy made some emergency fixes.

So, how could I update the local master branch without loss of work? I think I should commit my work, pull from origin/master again, and merge with my own branch. Is that the right thing to do? I didn't do this yet beacause I'm not secure about it. It's too many work, and lose it would be really to bad.

Comment: Commit everything and then do a `git pull --rebase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's too many work, and lose it would be really to bad.

First of all: you can simply copy your complete repository locally. `git` does not do any kind of magic in the filesystem; it lives in completely normal files.

In fact, if you experiment with stuff, you can simply copy your directory (using `cp` or whatever file utility you prefer) and work on that copy.

> So, how could I update the local master branch without loss of work? I think I should commit my work, pull from origin/master again, and merge with my own branch.

Something like that, yes.

```
git add ...
git commit
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

The `git pull` is functionally equal to `git fetch origin ; git merge origin/master`. So you do not need to do another merge afterwards. After the pull, you will have your changes and their changes in your `master`. The pull is also where you may encounter conflicts and will have to resolve those before you can continue.

Answer (score 2):

There can be different ways to do that. I think if you not add these changes to master move these changes to new branch as

```
git checkout -b tempbranch
```

after that `git add .` and then `git commit -m "message"`

Then again go to master as `git checkout master` after switch to master pull your changes as

`git pull origin master`

once you pull changes run final command as 
`git merge tempbranch`

Comment: That's what a I thought. Can I merge my branch with updated master with no conflict?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to develop a feature in its own branch (i.e. starting from `master` or, better, `develop` branch).
[git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) provides guidance and tools integrated in git (and a lot of git GUI client applications) to simplify this ond other common tasks.

In your scenario, there are some different things you can do, depending on the branching strategy and procedures you want to put in place.

If you made your changes directly in `master` branch, the more simple one is to:

1. commit your changes (locally, don't push)
2. rebase your commits over master (git pull --rebase)

Depending on how you want to "manage" or keep your commits (if you made more than one), you can just rebase all your commits, or interactively rebase (and "squash" some commits into fewer).

Comment: Yes, I have my own branch. Rebase will automatically update my master?

Comment: @user2132073 then please edit your question to include this information, because the answer may be better tailored or your scenario. (my suggestion for git-flow then is even more valuable)